# ISO-8601 String to Date in Google Sheets cell

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, iso8601

I have a bunch of ISO-8601 formatted strings in a column of my sheet.  How can I get google sheets to treat them as Dates so I can do math on them (difference in minutes between two cells, for example)?  I tried just `=Date("2015-05-27T01:15:00.000Z")` but no-joy.  There has to be an easy way to do this.  Any advice?

Comment: I find it more than a little surprising that formal ISO-8601 is the *one* date format that Google does not support.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

To get an actual Date value which you can format using normal number formatting...

`=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,1,10)) + TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,8))`

eg.

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 2016-02-22T05:03:21Z | 2/22/16 5:03:21 AM |

- Assumes timestamps are in UTC
- Ignores milliseconds (though you could add easily enough)

The [`DATEVALUE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039) function turns a formatted date string into a value, and [`TIMEVALUE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267350) does the same for times. In most spreadsheets dates & times are represented by a number where the integer part is days since 1 Jan 1900 and the decimal part is the time as a  fraction of the day. For example, 11 June 2009 17:30 is about 39975.72917.

The above formula parses the date part and the time part separately, then adds them together.

Comment: This solution is good.  It's better than the accepted one.  At least this returns a numeric Date (Time) value, not a string.  I've noticed that if a timezone offset is given, it's just ignored.  Also, the assumption of the character positions in the string makes this solution short and probably faster than several substitution and split function calls. 

Comment: you can just add the tz at the end. ... + (10/24) where 10 is the offset

Comment: This solution is better than the accepted one. It also works for iso8601 with timezone in +xx:xx formats, e.g,: 2018-08-18T19:11:25+00:00 that is in UTC. I suppose that the obtained datetime value has the timezone of current locale. In my case this is not an issue because I'm more interested in computing rough stats and time deltas.

Comment: It sucks this remains the right answer 31 years after the ISO8601 spec was introduced -- but it is! I also needed to support timezones -- optional ones, including minute offsets -- and wound up with this monster: `=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,1,10)) + TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,8)) + if(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1,24,3))), VALUE(MID(A1,24,3))/24, 0) + if(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1,29,2))), VALUE(MID(A1,29,2))/60/24, 0)`

Comment: @JanneAnnala It works for me.  When you say "replace the commas", which commas do you mean?  There are no commas in the original string.

Comment: Has anybody made milliseconds work? It seems to round to seconds when made into a datetime object. I'm getting the impression this just won't work for plotting the precise details of events spanning a 23.2s period.

Answer (score 42):

I found it much simpler to use `=SUM(SPLIT(A2,"TZ"))`

Format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000` to see the date value as ISO-8601 again.

Comment: This solution is not bad. It returns a numeric Date (Time) value as requested, instead of a string as in the accepted answer. It works best with GMT timestamps, not those with timezone offsets. If an offset is given, this solution uses a time of "0". This solution is clever and short, although not as correct as [the other answer](/a/36176351/543738), but better than many string function calls. 

Comment: This also handles milliseconds properly

Answer (score 16):

Try this

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Z",""),"T"),1),"yyyy-mm-dd")," ",TEXT(INDEX(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Z",""),"T"),2),"hh:mm:ss"))
```

Where **A1** can be a cell with ISO-8601 formatted string or the string itself.

Comment: Hmmm.  This doesn't exactly look "easy", but I'll give it a whirl.  I was really hoping that there was already one function to just do it.

Comment: This solution returns a string, not a Date type as @BobKuhar wanted.  When I tested it with ISO 8601 time string of, `2016-07-26T11:12:06.711-0400`, the result was `2016-07-26 11:12:06.711-0400`.  As a GMT time string (without timezone offset), `2016-07-26T11:12:06.711Z` became `2016-07-26 11:12:07`.  This solution just reformats the ISO 8601 string.

Comment: You have to Split the result, to break it down to "2016-07-26" and "11:12:07". These two cells will be formatted as Date and Time.

Answer (score 4):

Open Apps Script and paste this [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) into the editor.

```
function isoDate(isoDateString) {
  return new Date(isoDateString)
}
```

Use it with a formula like so:

```
=isoDate("2023-01-06T22:37:12Z")
```

The result will be displayed as a date in Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using a regex replace is a much simpler, clean, and readable way of doing it:

```
=regexreplace(A1, "T|Z", " ") + B1
```

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-04-17T16:29:20.085Z | -3:00:00 | 1080805:29:20 | 4/17/2023 13:29:20 |

- `A1` is the value to be formatted;
- `B1` is the timezone difference in your region;
- `C1` has the formula and no formatting;
- `D1` has the same formula and is formatted as `Date Time`.

The regex replaces the letters T and Z with a space.

The `+ B1` part will add the time difference to get the final value in your timezone.

If you want, instead of using a cell, you can hard code it in the formula.

```
=regexreplace(A1, "T|Z", " ") + "-3:00"
```

Or, if you don't want to get this difference in the formula you can just remove the `+ B1` part

```
=regexreplace(A1, "T|Z", " ")
```

Answer (score -1):

I use the following Apps Script functions to convert ISO8601 timestamps to serial datetimes in the respective spreadsheet's time zone:

```js
/** JS Date to Excel DateTime (AKA SERIAL_NUMBER date).
 *
 * @param date A JavaScript date object, possibly representing a datetime like 2022-11-11T15:24:00.000Z..
 * @param timeZoneOffsetMillies The time zone offset of the target serial date time (usually the one of the sheet).
 *
 * @return A Excel serial date like 44876.641666666605.
 */
const dateToSerialDateTime = function(date, timeZoneOffsetMillies) {
    /** Milliseconds per day (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000). */
    const MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY = 86400000;
    const timeZoneOffsetDays = timeZoneOffsetMillies / MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY;
    return ((date.getTime() / MILLISECONDS_PER_DAY) + 25569) + timeZoneOffsetDays; // 1970-01-01 - 1900-01-01 = 25569
};


/** Get the the timezone offset in milliseconds.
 *
 * @param timeZone The time zone in text format, ie. "Europe/Paris"
 * @return {number} Time zone offset in milliseconds.
 */
const getTimeZoneOffset = function(timeZone) {
    const strOffset = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "Z");
    const offsetSeconds = ((+(strOffset.substring(0, 3))) * 3600) + ((+strOffset.substring(3)) * 60);
    return offsetSeconds * 1000;
}


/**
 * Returns the current sheets timezone.
 *
 * @return The current sheets timezone in IANA time zone database name format (ie Europe/Berlin).
 * @customfunction
 */
function TIMEZONE() {
    return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
}


/**
 * Returns the current sheets timezone offset in milliseconds.
 *
 * @return The current sheets timezone offset in milliseconds.
 * @customfunction
 */
function TIMEZONE_OFFSET() {

    const tz = TIMEZONE();
    return tz != null ? getTimeZoneOffset(tz) : null;
}


/**
 * Convert ISO8601 timestamp strings (ie. 2022-11-22T14:47:01+0100) to a Sheets serial datetime.
 *
 * @param {string|Array<Array<string>>} input Input ISO8601 date string to parse.
 *
 * @return {number} The native sheets "serial datetime" as double (format the field as Number->Date Time manually).
 * @customfunction
 */
function PARSE_ISO8601(input) {

    const tzOffsetMillies = TIMEZONE_OFFSET();
    const parseIso8601 = ts => ts ? dateToSerialDateTime(new Date(ts), tzOffsetMillies) : null;

    return Array.isArray(input) ? input.map(row => row.map(field => parseIso8601(field))) : parseIso8601(input);
}
```