# Safest way to write a time (datetime)

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a server application that is making calls to a google spreadsheet to write some values. What is the safest format I should use to write a date to a spreadsheet safely so it is interpreted as a (date)time appropriately ?

For instance if my application writes a date in the iso format 8601 format, the date won't be parsed by google spreadsheet, `2019-06-11T15:57:30+02:00` is interpreted as text and then I would need to resort to questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492832/iso-8601-string-to-date-in-google-sheets-cell).

On the opposite, writing `2019-06-11 15:57:30` does work, yet I am losing the information of the time zone, and the actual time I wanted to write was `2019-06-11 13:57:30 +0`.

**What format should I use to write DateTime objects in Google spreadsheets?**

Do you recommend systematically converting to UTC and then applying format like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS +TZ`?

I want to highlight that I'm working in an international context, (mainly in France) and I want to avoid confusing formats (like dd-mm-yyyy vs mm-dd-yyyy) and retain timezone information if possible.

Comment: The date/time value in the spreadsheet is typically stored as a floating point number. It's a combination of the integer number of days since 1-Jan-1900. The decimal part of the number is the fractional part of a single day. So 43627.48 converts to the date 11-Jun-2019 at 11:31am. Notice that the time zone is not specified. That's up to you to interpret the time zone. So you'll have to apply any time zone conversions before storing the value. Applying formatting rules for display don't affect the time zone.

Comment: Store utc millis and tz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem some time ago.
Unfortunately G-Sheets does not recognize timezones in the date/time fields. If you do need it for processing, you need to store it as a text, or UTC time + another column for the time zone.