# Convert string to datetime and add 5:30 hours to it in google sheets using js or apps script

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have multiple rows with datetime in string format and I want to convert it to date time and then add 5.30 hours to it.

How can this be done?

```
2020-06-05T7:30:00Z
2020-08-25T18:30:00Z
2020-08-28T18:30:00Z
2020-07-01T7:30:00Z
2020-06-10T6:30:00Z
```

Expected output:

```
2020-06-05 13:00:00
2020-08-25 00:00:00
2020-08-28 00:00:00
2020-07-01 13:00:00
2020-06-10 12:00:00
```

Comment: It looks like you don't mean 5.3 hours you mean 5 hours and 30 minutes.  Is that corrrect?

Comment: Hi Colen, can you please show us the code you have tried? Please check out the "How to ask" part of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30492832/iso-8601-string-to-date-in-google-sheets-cell) to a similar question, you could do something like:

`=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,1,10)) + TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,8)) + TIME(5,30,0)`

This should add the date, the time, and the requested 5:30.  However, it doesn't handle the input as provided.  The first, fourth, and fifth entries break the formula.  If the input can be changed so that the hour field always has 2 digits, then this formula works.  Here is an example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Oh5_1yOylNwxHx1znnxFK5_1e-Y4gERpInFBag4eMw/edit?usp=sharing

EDIT: The problem is not the 2 digit hour, it's the Z on the end indicating Zulu (i.e. UTC) time.  So, we could just strip that character out, but it according to the [documentation for the TIMEVALUE function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267350?hl=en), it doesn't support timezones.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function add(dts,hr,min) {
  var dts=dts||"2020-06-05T7:30:00Z";//date time string
  dts=dts.slice(0,-1);//remove Z
  var hr=hr||5;
  var min=min||30;
  var add=hr*3600000+min*60000;//add 7 hours and 30 minutes
  if(dts) {
    let t0=dts.split('T');
    let t1=t0[0].split('-');
    let t2=t0[1].split(':');
    var stv=new Date(t1[0],Number(t1[1])-1,t1[2],t2[0],t2[1],t2[2]).valueOf();//month-1
    var dt=new Date(stv+add);
    var dso=Utilities.formatDate(dt,Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss");
    console.log(dso)
    return dt;
  }
}
```