# How can I convert one time zone to another in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using apiway for google sheet and Facebook lead ads integration. The sheets auto updates when a new leads comes in but the problem is the time zone is  **London UTC+00:00**, which I need to change to **Islamabad, Karachi UTC+05:00**.

I want to write a function that can do this conversion for me every time a lead comes in.

I have tried searching on **Google**, **Stackoverflow**, and also **Google References**. However, the information is too overwhelmed for me and I've no clue where to start.

I'm not a programmer/coder, I learned some basics of **Java** and **C** in my college and I've started learning **Google App Script**, so I'm clueless.

Can someone please help me writing  a function and more importantly walk me through to the code.

Here is a screenshot of the sheet that I'm managing.

[image: Google Work Sheet]

Comment: Currently, are you converting the dates by yourself? Have you tried changing the Time zone in Spreadsheet settings?  ([File]-[Spreadsheet settings])

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yes I tried that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should use formula rather than script because if you use the script, you should consider the target range of the process, on the other hand, if you use the formula, you don't need it, and it is easier.

I assume that the data type of the Date column is **text**. You can add a column next to the Date column then fill the column with the following formula. (A2 is an example)

```
=SUM(SPLIT(A2,"T+")) + TIME(5, 0, 0)
```

`SUM(SPLIT(A2, "T+"))` is a formula that splits the Date text and sums up the time value.
(The last value `0000` is ignored because it's zero)

`TIME(5, 0, 0)` is a formula that changes the date from London to Karachi.

This formula is inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37197505).

I made a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g9XogQTiFgZ6pvWdR43GKjNhq2T9_Grxe3yz_ZWEzCc/edit?usp=sharing) based on my answer. pls, check it :)

Comment: Note: This solution does not follow timezone conversions eg. daylight savings might see times move from -5 to -6 for a period